# How to solve $y''+Ay'+By=a+bt+ct^{2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the solution of this second-order non-homogeneous will be of the form $y = y_{p} + y_{c}$.

First I find the solution to the homogeneous DE: $y''+Ay'+By=0$, with the characteristic equation $r^{2}+Ar+B=0$. However, it's hard to actually get the roots since I don't know what $A$ and $B$ are.

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

**EDIT:** By using the quadratic formula: $r = \frac{-A\pm \sqrt{A^{2}-4B}}{2}$.

So we don't really know about the form of the complementary solution, $y_{c}$.

Now, we find the particular solution of $y''+Ay'+By=a+bt+ct^{2}$.

Let $y_{p} = A_{1}t^{2}+B_{1}t+C_{1}$.

So $y'_{p} = 2A_{1}t+B_{1}$ and $y''_{p} = 2A_{1}$.

We substitute $y_{p}$ and it's first and second derivatives back into the non-homogeneous DE to obtain:

$t^{2}(A_{1}B)+t(2AA_{1}+BB_{1})+(2A_{1}+AB_{1}+BC_{1})=ct^{2}+bt+a$

So $$A_{1}B=c;$$
$$2AA_{1}+BB_{1}=b;$$
$$2A_{1}+AB_{1}+BC_{1}=a.$$

From the above equations I obtain $A_{1} = \frac{B}{c}$, $B_{1} = \frac{cb}{B}-2A$, and $C_{1} = \frac{a - \frac{B}{c} - \frac{ACb}{B}+2A^{2}}{B}$.

So the particular solution, $$y_{p} = (\frac{B}{c}) t^{2} + (\frac{cb}{B}-2A)t + \frac{a - \frac{B}{c} - \frac{ACb}{B}+2A^{2}}{B}$$.

Then how do I write down expression for the general solution, $y$.

Is it just $$y = (\frac{B}{c}) t^{2} + (\frac{cb}{B}-2A)t + \frac{a - \frac{B}{c} - \frac{ACb}{B}+2A^{2}}{B} + y_{c}?$$

Comment: you need to find ?$$y_{p}$$

Comment: @user36829: You can just write the roots of the homogeneous in terms of the variables as $m_{1,2} = \dfrac 12 (\pm~\sqrt{A^2-4B}-A)$ and then move to the particular. Those are then represented in the homogeneous using exponentials with those general roots.

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Only $y_{p}$? I thought that I had to find both $y_{c}$ and $y_{p}$.

Comment: You can find an expression for the roots in terms of $A$ and $B$. Then you probably will want to break it up into cases, $A^2-4B\gt 0$, $A^2-4B=0$, $A^2-4B\lt 0$. If you are willing to use complex numbers, there are only two cases, $A^2-4B=0$ and $A^2-4B\ne 0$.

Comment: For finding a particular solution, do it as if $A$ and $B$ were specific numbers, like $10$ and $3$. You will get equations that involve the parameters $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay, I will make an edit soon.

Comment: In your edit, we need other letters. Look for a particular solution of the shape $pt^2+qt+r$, and I think the troubles will disappear.

Comment: the particular solution should be taken the form $y_p=A_1t^2+B_1t+C_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the particular soultion,we assume
$$y_p=A_1t^2+B_1t+C_1$$
$$y'_p=2A_1t+B_1$$
$$y''_p=2A_1$$

substitute in D.E to get
$$2A_1+A(2A_1t+B_1)+B(A_1t^2+B_1t+C_1)=a+bt+ct^2$$

$$BA_1=c$$
$$A_1=c/B$$
so the $c$,$B$ are known 
$$2AA_1+BB_1=b$$
$$B_1=(b-2A(c/B))/B$$
$$2A_1+AB_1+BC_1=a$$
$$C_1=(a-2A_1-AB_1)/B$$

If you want to find the complementary solution
$$r^2+Ar+B=0$$
$$r=0.5A\mp \sqrt{0.25A^2-B}$$ 
$$r=\alpha \pm \beta $$
$$y_c=K_1e^{\alpha + \beta}+K_2e^{\alpha - \beta}$$
$$y_c=e^\alpha(K_1e^\beta+K_2e^{-\beta})$$
If the $\beta$ is complex part, you can change the exponential to $sin$ and $cos$

Comment: You have errors in your substitution.